# spring with ehcache, cache missing in non-cacheable function calls

Tags: spring-cache

This question is really hard to describe clearly just in text.
shortly, if call a function marked with @Cacheable directly, 
all as expected. however, if call this @Cacheable function in another 
function without @Cacheable, cache hits is not as expected.

please see the code: 
http://www.devbeacon.com/d/cache1.zip

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation is pretty explicit about that](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html#cache-annotation-enable)

> In proxy mode (which is the default), only external method calls coming in through the proxy are intercepted. This means that self-invocation, in effect, a method within the target object calling another method of the target object, will not lead to an actual caching at runtime even if the invoked method is marked with @Cacheable - considering using the aspectj mode in this case.

Your internal method call completely bypass the proxy. `query2` should have the `@Cacheable` as well. If you don't want that, you need to use the AspectJ mode instead.